# How to mark src folder as Sources Root through linux terminal?

Tags: python, linux, terminal, pycharm

I am trying to run a python file from terminal. It has a bunch of imports from modules I wrote, and those modules also import from other modules from throughout my project. As PyCharm was my main editor, I could mark the src directory as Sources Root, which allowed me to import other modules in two ways. Say I have a module shared, I could import from it as:

```
from src.shared.timer import Timer
```

But also as:

```
from shared.timer import Timer
```

When I run my script main.py from within pycharm everything runs perfectly
The problem is that when I run main.py from command line, my imports give error "No module named shared" or "No module named src" depending on whether I call from the top-level directory or from the src directory. Either way, I can never get all imports right. Is there a way to mark my src directory as Sources Root, similar to in PyCharm? I want to avoid refactoring everything and then finding out there is some other issue.

from top level directory in repository, I tried to run

```
python3.8 -m src.main.py
```

and got

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'shared'

Comment: Okay so it ran without any errors from the src directory once I replaced all src.some_module imports with just some_module. However, it would still be nice if I could mark the src folder as Sources Root similar to in PyCharm. Let me know if you know the answer please